# pattern MMM/yyyy in calendar not works with Primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, calendar, date-format

I try a simple calendar with primefaces 3.5 and I need show only month and year, so I use the pattern MMMM/yyyy and I show the name of month and year, this is the code:

```java
 <p:calendar  value="#{controlador.fecha}" pattern="MMMM/yyyy">
               
 </p:calendar>
```

And the bean:

```java
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class Controlador {

   private Date fecha;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init(){
       this.fecha = new Date();
   }

   /**
   *@return the fecha
   */
   public Date getFecha() {
      return fecha;
   }

   /**
    * @param fecha the fecha to set
    */
   public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
      this.fecha = fecha;
   }

}
```

This show the following:

[image]

The trouble is that when I try to change the date the calendar does not work.

How do I make it work?

Comment: What do you mean by _when I try to change the date the calendar does not work_?

Comment: by default I show a date, but I need choose other date, I need to show like a use the attribute inline or navigate

Comment: What about adding the `mode` attribute ?
`<p:calendar value="#{controlador.fecha}" pattern="MMMM/yyyy" mode="inline" />`

Comment: You want to show the date in special format as indicated your question title or to modify the date by some way ?

Comment: Have you found a solution?